# Binding Kendo grid to a Complex dataSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a div which I am converting to a Kendo Grid in Jquery.

```
 divSearchGrid.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                var webMethod = "Portal.aspx/DisplayNotes";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: urlSearch,
                    data: paramsSearch,
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result.d);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    selectable: "row",
    autoSync: true,
    editable: true,// "inline",
    navigatable: true,
    columnMenu: true
})
```

It's Datasource is a List whose objects has another List as their properties.

Example 
Datasource : `[{a,b,c,List,g,h,i,},{a,b,c,List,g,h,i,},{a,b,c,List,g,h,i,}]`

and the List in above objects has following structure

**List** : `[{d},{e},{f}]`

I want to show my kendo grid with following columns:

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

How can I achieve this functionality.

Comment: Are the nested columns going to be editable ?

Comment: Your 'List' is in the wrong format, you have an array of object with no key/value pairs

Comment: @giltnerj0 yes the nested columns will also be editable

Comment: @dcodesmith Yes all a.b...,i are key/value pairs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to show the contents, you can simply bind multiple columns to the List object, and use the template property to display each one.

```
{ field: 'List', template: '#=List[0].value#' }
```

or similar.  Of course it relies on List having the same number of properties for each main list Item (i.e. always {d},{e},{f}).

If you need to edit these fields, you will need to employ a custom editor for each {d},{e},{f} field

Here is a small sample using a list with a nested list. (Second grid is just for testing actual values are changing).  Not exactly sure how your data is structured, or what your data types are, but hopefully this will help.

http://jsbin.com/AWogIpO/1/edit

Comment: Your solution is very close to what i am expecting but in my case I will not be knowing that inner list has how many properties then in that case what should be done.Is their any provision to use For loop for the inside list.

Comment: Will each main list items' sublist have the same number of items?

Comment: Yes each main list items' sublist have the same number of items.

Comment: At the same time I want the header to be List[0].name of the column.

Comment: Moreover in this way we will not be able to do sorting,grouping and other inbuilt features which are required in my scenario.

Comment: I think if you have to have sorting/grouping along with editing etc. you either need to restructure your data, or find a different tool as I don't think kendo can handle this.

Comment: Changing the structure of the data is not possible in my case.Can anyone help in this regard.